Resizing a Map with react-simple-maps in React
I'm attempting to display a map of France using react-simple-maps. However, I'm encountering an issue where the map appears too small. Despite trying various methods such as CSS adjustments, modifying width and height attributes and using ZoomableGroup, I haven't been able to scale it up successfully. Could someone assist me in resolving this issue?
Here's my code:
import { Page } from "@/components/ui/page";
import {
  ComposableMap,
  Geographies,
  Geography,
  ZoomableGroup,
} from "react-simple-maps";

const geoUrl =
  "https://france-geojson.gregoiredavid.fr/repo/departements.geojson";

export default () => {
  return (
    <Page className="gap-10 w-full">
      <Page.Header className="flex flex-col gap-4 items-start">
        <h1 className="mt-[70px] text-3xl">Carte</h1>
        <h2 className="text-xs text-dark opacity-65">Carte des departements</h2>
      </Page.Header>

      <Page.Body>
        <ComposableMap
          projectionConfig={{
            scale: 155,
          }}
          width={800}
          height={400}
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
        >
          <ZoomableGroup disablePanning zoom={1}>
            <Geographies geography={geoUrl}>
              {({ geographies }) =>
                geographies.map((geo) => (
                  <Geography key={geo.rsmKey} geography={geo} />
                ))
              }
            </Geographies>
          </ZoomableGroup>
        </ComposableMap>
      </Page.Body>
    </Page>
  );
};


Here's the image:


I was facing the same issue with the France (and neighbouring countries) map myself. I was able to solve it by trying out different configurations. This is what worked for me:
<ComposableMap
    width={800}
    height={600}
    projection="geoMercator"
    projectionConfig={{
      scale: 900,
      center: [0, 52],
    }}
>

I'd advise you to do the following:
First make sure your scale is a small value (don't use zoomable component just yet). If the map appears, no matter how small, try to increase the scale value and see if it still appears or disappears. If it disappears then use zoomable component to drag and get it on the view and try again with different configurations.
Then position the map using center [x,y] array. For me I found out that centering x at 0 worked for me, and I only had to adjust the y values to make it center of my div. This is how my map appears with my configuration:


Thanks !! It's exactly what i was looking for :)
